# Python init code add value in field after creating folder

Tags: pyqgis

I wrote a Python init code for a form. It creates folder and subfolder if the value of a field is "Si".

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import os
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.utils import *

from qgis.PyQt.QtWidgets import QWidget

def crea_cartelle(layer, idx, path):
  layer = iface.activeLayer()
  idx = layer.fieldNameIndex('codice_opera') 
  folder = layer.fieldNameIndex('crea_directory')
  path = "\\\\xx.xx.x.xx\\dati_gis\\archivio_opere_tv\\"
  for feat in layer.getFeatures():
    attrs = feat.attributes()
    if attrs[folder]== "Si":
      if not os.path.exists(path + attrs[idx]):

        os.makedirs(path + attrs[idx]+os.sep+ attrs[idx]+"_documenti")
        os.makedirs(path + attrs[idx]+os.sep+ attrs[idx]+"_foto")
```

Well after creating folders I would like adding a code that inserts the hotlink values (es. path + attrs[idx]+os.sep+ attrs[idx]+"_foto") in fields "link_foto" an "link_document"

I have tried to add this code:

```
        layer = iface.activeLayer() 
        feats = layer.getFeatures()
        field_index = layer.dataProvider().fieldNameIndex('link_foto')
        layer.startEditing()
        l_foto = "some text"
        layer.changeAttributeValue(feat.id(), field_index, l_foto)

layer.commitChanges()
```

But It returns an error for layer that doesn't recognize.
Any suggestions is welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following should hopefully work:

```
from qgis.utils import iface
import os

def crea_cartelle(dialog, layer, feature):
    layer = iface.activeLayer()
    idx = layer.fieldNameIndex('codice_opera') 
    folder = layer.fieldNameIndex('crea_directory')
    path = "D:/prova/"
    provider = layer.dataProvider()
    updateMap = {}
    fieldIdx = provider.fields().indexFromName( 'link_foto')
    features = provider.getFeatures()
    for feature in features:
        attrs = feature.attributes()
        cod=str(attrs[idx])
        if attrs[folder]== "Si":
            if not os.path.exists(path + cod):
                os.makedirs(path+cod+"/"+cod+"_documenti")
                os.makedirs(path+cod+"/"+cod+"_foto")
            updateMap[feature.id()] = { fieldIdx: path+cod+"/"+cod+'_foto'}
            provider.changeAttributeValues( updateMap )
```

Then type `crea_cartelle` as the **Function name**:

[image: Python init method]

I replaced `os.sep` with just a forward slash as I prefer using these but you can change it back if you want.

---

*Tested on QGIS 2.18.2*.

Comment: thanks Joseph. Using your code when the form appears the layer became off (not editing) and it's impossible to insert values. Removing " layer.commitChanges()" it doesn't insert "link_foto" value.

Comment: @DanielePiccolo - Thanks, yes couldn't test it yesterday but I have now and included a (hopefully) working solution :)

Comment: But I also need the other code (create folder) too.

Comment: If I only use it, it doesn't work

Comment: Joseph. It create the folders but doesn't write in the field. I don't understand why but No error appears.

Comment: @DanielePiccolo - Check your field names, the ones you mentioned in your code exceed the 10 character limit. Are you sure they match? I changed these field names when testing and it worked for me.

Comment: I'm using postgis layers and the code in python console work fine

Comment: @DanielePiccolo - I just tested this on a postgis layer and it still works fine. Could you [edit](https://gis.stackexchange.com/posts/243765/edit) your question to include the **exact** code you are using?

Comment: I'm using your code copied and pasted. I don't understand , I continue to try

Comment: Great!!! I have closed and reopened QGIS and now it works fine. Thank you very much.

Comment: @DanielePiccolo - Most welcome, glad you solved it :)